# How do you call a function in a class that works in another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm working on a class that looks like this:

```
public class MatchmakingService  {
    private bool working;
    private List<MatchmakingUser> matchmakingUsers;
    // ...

    public MatchmakingService()
    {
        matchmakingUsers = new List<MatchmakingUser>();
    }

    public void StartService () {
        var thread = new Thread(this.MatchmakingWork);
        working = true;
        thread.Start();
    }

    void MatchmakingWork () {
        while (working)
        {
            // some work
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    // ...
    public void AddMatchmakingUser(MatchmakingUser user)
    {
        matchmakingUsers.Add(user);
    }
}
```

Now I'm worried about matchmakingUsers list so I figured I'd just call this AddMatchmakingUser to execute in this service thread, but don't really know how to. I've read about Dispatcher class but either mono in Unity doesn't have it or it's a different technology entirely. Basically I'd like to do:

```
MatchmakingService mmService = new MatchmakingService();
mmService.Start();

// sometime later when needed
mmService.Somehowinvokeinworkingthread(mmService.AddMatchMakingUser(...));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `AddMatchmakingUser` from any thread and synchronize all the code that's accesing the list to prevent them from occuring at the same time and causing a race condition:

```
public void AddMatchmakingUser(MatchmakingUser user)
{
    lock (matchmakingUsers)
    {
        matchmakingUsers.Add(user);
    }
}
```

Do the same inside `MatchmakingWork` whenever you are accessing the list.

Comment: matchmakingUsers will be used for complex operations in their working thread, I can't lock risking too much time spent on waiting for it to be freed

Comment: As long as most of the time the `MatchmakingWork` thread is the only one working with the list, there won't be any waiting. The waiting will only happen when you modify from the list. I assume this should be a rare occurence. If locking every list access individually still poses a performance problem, you can lock a larger code block, e.g. even a full loop iteration. The downside will be, that calling code will have to wait for this to complete before it can modify the list (which might be a good idea nevertheless for the sake of consistence).

Comment: Alternatively, you could put additional users in a separate `ConcurrentQueue` when calling `AddMatchmakingUser` and process that queue at the beginning of each iteration in `MatchmakingWork`, i.e. move them to the actual list you are processing. This way you won't need any locking at all.

Comment: Oh yeah that's a good idea. I guess I'll make a queue for all the requests to the service.